# Unable to load another page in JHipster on Production

Tags: gruntjs, jhipster

I have an issue with the `Pprod` profile.  I have created two pages: `index.html` and `profile.html`

When I run the project with production profile then the index page is working fine for me.  I.e. it converts all `CSS`, `JS` and replaces all `HTML` with the new URL.

If I replace `profile.html` with `index.html` then again it is all working fine for me.  I.e. it converts all `CSS`, `JS` and replaces all `HTML` with the new URL.

But, if I run both pages simultaneously, then only `index.html` is working fine for me and `profile.html` is not.

On `profile.html` page HTML, the URL is not changed with `script.js` and `main.css` file.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) abc.com/styles/postLogin.css
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) abc.com/scripts/profile.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) abc.com/scripts/main.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) abc.com/scripts/profile/app/app.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404  (Not Found) abc.com/scripts/profile/directive/profile-directive.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) abc.com/scripts/profile/controller/profile-controller.js
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) abc.com/scripts/profile/service/profile-service.js

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to upgrade to our latest 0.8.3 version, which I just released 2 minutes ago. It fixes several issues in "production" mode, which probably affect you:

http://jhipster.github.io/2014/01/29/jhipster-release-0.8.3.html

Secondly, your main problem is that JHipster is designed to create a "single page" webapp, so obviously if you have two Web pages you will have some minor trouble. The only thing you need to do, AFAIK, is to add your file to the WebConfigurer.initStaticResourcesProductionFilter class, just after the "/index.html" line:

```
staticResourcesProductionFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/profile.html");
```

That way your file will be served by the "production" filter.